# Patching a closed source network application to read from file

Tags: c, sockets, fuzzing, custom-protocol

So let me explain, I want to fuzz a closed source application named `Y` that implements a custom protocol let's name the protocol `X`. `Y` is written in C.
Is there a way to patch the `send/read` family functions to read from file instead of the socket?
Could this potentially work for the AFL/AFL++ fuzzer?
Keep in mind the application is developed for UNIX-like ecosystems.

Comment: I rephrased to at least avoid asking for opinions (which would make this off-topic). I am afraid that this is still off-topic for other reasons however. Please see [help/on-topic].

Comment: It would probably be easier to just configure your network in a way that the app thinks it's talking to a real remote, but it's talking to some dummy app of your own.

Comment: @AKX thanks for the reply ! Do you have any practical examples ?? e.g. a blog post would be helpful

Comment: @Shad3 a quick google found https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323791/how-can-i-redirect-outbound-traffic-to-another-ip-using-iptables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that easily by making bridges between named pipes (fifos) and TCP connections through netcat.

Create two files (named pipes):

```
mkfifo /tmp/program_input /tmp/program_output
```

Now, make a bridge between these files and the application.

In case the application is a TCP/IP Client, your bridge will be a TCP/IP Server:

```
tail -f /tmp/program_input | nc -kl 127.0.0.1 50000 | tee /tmp/program_output > /dev/null
```

Then you'll have to configure the application's peer IP address as the IP of the host where your bridge runs. Port also must match and is arbitrary. ("50000" in the example above.)

In case you can't change the IP address/TCP port the application uses, you'll have to map these on your router to the IP/port of your bridge application (see "port forwarding").

If the application is a TCP/IP Server, create a TCP/IP client as a bridge:

```
tail -f /tmp/program_input | nc <application_ip_address> <application_port> | tee /tmp/program_output > /dev/null
```

If you want to write something to the networking application you're analyzing, write to `/tmp/program_input`. Read `/tmp/program_output` to see its output.

I'm not too familiar with AFL/AFL++, but you can certainly communicate with the application directly or also make socket/file bridges for the fuzzer as well.

Comment: Just tested this and it works like charm. Thanks!!! I had of course to edit AFL/AFL++ i had of course to code a bridge for the file, editing AFL's code but at the end of the day it does its job. Thanks again!!